# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base [...]org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps[...] does not exist or is not a readable directory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, illegalargumentexception

I am getting this exception in eclipse-jee-Kepler-SR1-win32

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\praveen\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\advanced java does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5077)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The issues might come from the JDK series. I experienced the same issues in most pc with win32 bit and some win64 bit. The issues solved when I tried to downgrade the jdk (JRE) series from 8 to 7. I think you may need these steps;

1. Check your Tomcat version, if you are using Tomcat 7 series you may need jre 7 series and below.
2. Just download the jre kit from here;
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html
3. Change the server preferences to Tomcat 7. ALWAYS CHECK!
4. Restart Eclipse. (I recommend you to use Luna. Its much more stable.)
5. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Build the project again, regenerate the war file and add it to the web module.Sometimes the generated war file will be corrupted or will not reflect the new changes.